# Is it safe to save the In app purchase SKU product id in strings.xml?

Tags: android

I have read the google provided In-app billing sample for billing library v3, link is as follow:
https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/main/ClassyTaxiJava

In the sample, it use public class Constants

```
public static final String BASIC_SKU = "basic_subscription";
public static final String PREMIUM_SKU = "premium_subscription";
```

for the whole app.
I am wondering if a user can decompile or unpack the apk and change the product string or exchange the SKU string so that there may happen that the bought item A but receive bought item B function.

So I want to use getString(R.string.SKU_itemA) and getString(R.string.SKU_itemB) to try to make the text less explicit in code searching. Will I do this be safer to avoid user change?

Answer (score 1):

If you have signature verification in your app, the only way to modify your app is to somehow defeat the signature verification. I suggest that you verify your app's signature, and it will protect you from any issues related to app cloning or app modification.
It does not make sense to just protect the SKU somehow: if the users are able to modify your app, they are also able to remove the check if the subscription has been purchased.